# Conditional covariance of AR(1)

Tags: time-series, covariance, autoregressive, conditional-expectation

I am trying to derive the conditional covariance of an AR(1) process, $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+h})$.

I have been trying to solve it taking in account the law of iterated expectations (LIE). However, I couldn't find a successful way to do so.

Comment: If this is a homework exercise, consider adding a `self-study` tag. You can read about it more [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You should then show what you have attempted to do so far to get hints on what the next steps are. If this is not a homework exercise, I think you should be able to find the relevant derivation in time series textbooks (or perhaps even in some posts here on Cross Validated -- take a closer look at them).

Comment: Conditional on what?

Comment: It dissapeared but I was trying to derive the covariance at "t-n" of {Y_t,Y_t+h}, that is, Cov_t-n[Y_t,Y_t+h]. The problem arises when trying to incorporate the time dependancy to the derivation